# How to set to a variable, the result of a expression

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I need to extract the date of a file, then use this string as part of the name of a new file. I tried to solve this using the next commands:

First I get the details of the file and redirect the output to a temporary file.

```
DIR c:/myfolder/thefile.txt >> tmp.txt
```

Then I use FINDSTR to get the line that contains the date, if exist a way to get only the date I didn't found it:

```
FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt
```

The output is:

```
10/04/2012 07:55 66,029 thefile.txt
```

Now I want to set this result to a variable:

```
SET vartmp=FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt
```

It seems that it worked, because when i put %vartmp% returns the result:

```
10/04/2012 07:55 66,029 thefile.txt
```

But when I try to extract a part of vartmp, begin the problems:

```
ECHO %vartmp:~0,2%
```

It's returning me the string "FI" when I expected "10", seems that vartmp is saving the expression and not the result of the expression,  I'm trying assign the result of the expression to an another tempvar, then extract a substring of tempvar but nothing has changed.

Comment: Give us the complete script. I can figure out how you set vartmp.

Answer (score 1):

The FOR command can be used to chop up a line into tokens so you can grab just the part you want. With /f you can run it on the output of other commands, in this case the output of DIR filtered with FIND.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('dir thefile.txt ^| Find "thefile.txt"') do (
set vartmp=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but could change `SET vartmp=FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt` to

```
FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
SET /p vartmp =< tmp2.txt
DEL tmp2.txt
```

Comment: Its just sad that it has to be done this way on windows.....

Comment: @Antoniossss you can make really simple microservices in .NET Core now. So basically just use C# instead

Comment: @Antoniossss Did you check it out dude? It's FOSS and will run on anysystem.

Answer (score 0):

When following your examples I found same result however if I replaced the line:

```
SET vartmp=FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt
```

with

```
for /f %i in ('FINDSTR [0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9] tmp.txt') do set vartmp=%i
```

then vartmp holds what you seek.  Note that you need single quotes there, double quotes won't work. Also if using in a batch file you need %%i in place of %i